# How to connect laptop with telephone using WI-FI? (ethernet)

Tags: networking, laptop, wireless-networking, ad-hoc-network, phone

What I did:

1. Added new wireless network in wireless network settings and gave it SSID
2. Gave laptop the IP like 192.168.0.1, mask: 255.255.255.0, gateway: 192.168.0.2
3. Gave the telephone with wifi the same mask but IP and gateway rewersed

If my steps are wrong please tell me the correct way to establish this connection via Wi-Fi.

**Update:**
The thing is that I want to connect these 2 devices (laptop and telephone) like you would connect 2 computers to transfer data without using internet. In that case you can use crossover cable, setup IPs like I did but I want to do this wirelessly.

And I did it this way because of [this article](http://www.digitgeek.com/how-to-connect-two-computers-using-a-direct-wi-fi-ad-hoc-connection/)
but in my case 2nd device should be telephone.

It should be 2-way communication.

Comment: Please expand the question, are you trying to get connectivity through your phone to your laptop or vice-versa?

Answer (score 1):

Why reverse the details on the telephone?

If the telephone is not the router then it should have the same gateway and subnet mask (and SSID) as the PC with a different IP address (say 192.168.0.3). If you cannot set this then I would suggest that you leave the IP address for the PC left as auto.

If the telephone is your router then you will not need to set it's IP address as it holds the Gateway IP address.

If none of this answers your problems then some more information regarding exactly what your hardware setup is would help.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to connect 2 devices in the same subnet you don't need to set the gateway (gateway by definition is a way out of the subnet).
2. If you cannot even connect to wireless it's not the issue with the ip but with the wireless :P Assuming you are creating Ad-hoc network - try to set Ad-hoc network mode to B-only in advanced settings of laptop wireless card.
3. Make sure that SSID broadcast is turned on.

Comment: ok, with this wireless I wrote sth by mistake, let's forget about it

still important is that i don't know how connect telephone and laptop via wifi (radio waves) to create local network, connection should be keeped only between these 2 devices

Comment: Wireless is good choice (assuming your phone supports it). When you are connecting 2 devices in the same subnet you can even leave the gateway blank (as I wrote before) - it doesn't impact the connection. The reason I suggested checking Ad-hoc wireless mode - if your laptop card works in n-mode and your phone supports only b/g they won't see each other. Setting it to B-only is a safe choice.
Can you see your laptops Ad-hoc network from any other device?
Also - using wireless assumes that your phone has some kind of net service accessible from computer. I would advice bluetooth.